# unable to display own error message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I am using codeigniter3. now i want to delete a record then it display database following error

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (soft.tbl_item_sub_category, CONSTRAINT
>   `tbl_item_sub_category_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES
>   tbl_item_category (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

the main problem is that it looks ugly to display database error. i want to display my own error message. so i use `$this->db->error()` but it doesn't work. here is my delete function. to handle this error message but it doesn't work.

delete function()

```
public function delete($table,$id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($table);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true; // to the controller
    }
    else {
         $error = $this->db->error(); // to the controller
    }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work? you can't access the error message? show *how* you are using the function.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Return false instead of `$error = $this->db->error();` and access `$this->db->error();` in the controller.

### Option 2

Your method modified...

```
public function delete($table,$id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($table);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true; // to the controller
    }
    else {
        $error = $this->db->error(); // to the controller
        return $error;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
if (($err = $this->some_model->delete($table,$id)) !== true) {
    print_r($err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this Code For Delete Records

**Controllere**

```
 public function($id)
 {
    $t = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id='$id'");
    $tt = $t->row_array();
    if($tt>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
         $false= $this->db->error();
         return $false;
    }
 }
```